# Fixed Length Record I/O in PHP

Tags: php, binary, fixed-length-record

I have read a fixed length Record from the file Using php. I have given the code below.

```
$f = fopen('data.txt', 'rb');

while (!feof($f)) {
  // read one segment of 52 bytes
  if ($s = fread($f, 52)) {
    // unpack the binary structure into an associative array
    print_r(unpack('ieid/ieage/a20name/a20city', $s));
  }
}

fclose($f);
```

Now i need to know How to write the Fixed Length record to the file. I searched in many web sites but still i didn't get the correct answer . How can i write the fixed Length record to the binary / text file ?

Comment: So you want to do the opposite of `fread` and `unpack`. Did you try `pack` and `fwrite`?

Comment: @leigh: now i tried. And i got the result. Thank you .

Comment: I can unpack the string with the correct format. But i didn't pack the same record into the string variable.

fwrite($fp, pack('i', $eid));  
fwrite($fp, pack('i', $eage));
fwrite($fp, pack('a20', $name)); 
fwrite($fp, pack('a20', city));
but i want to do this in a single line .